# Can I prevent deadlock using `WITH(NOLOCK)`?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, nolock

I have a table which I'm only `Insert`, `Delete` and `Select` (no `Update`s)

on Insert, Sometimes it used a session lock (`WITH (TABLOCKX)`)

I have a program using ADO which `Select` from the table using the `RecordSet::Open` command to open a simple sequential query.

like:

```
Select * from t1 where id >= @from_id And >= @to_id`
```

Or:

```
Select top(10) * from t1 where id >= @id Order by id
```

The id column is an `Identity` column.

When I'm open the query, sometimes I'm getting a deadlock. (the table is locked by the `Insert` query and the id column's index is locked by the `Select`)

I'm trying to prevent the deadlocks.

Should I open the select queries `WITH(NOLOCK)`? may it prevent the deadlocks?

Comment: WITH (NODEADLOCK)

Comment: Are you ok with the possibility of reading the same rows twice, skipping rows, seeing data never committed, and having your query fail with error? [Reference 1](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/08/but-nolock-is-okay-when-the-data-isnt-changing-right/), [Reference 2](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ so using  `WITH (NODEADLOCK)` is safe enough?

Comment: @shr - Phil was being facetious.  There is no such hint named `NODEADLOCK`

Answer (score 5):

A better idea would be to enable snapshot isolation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server

This will enable each transaction to have its own snapshot of data and will not lock, or block other transactions.